# Exibir de 1 até 1000 em C++ sem usar o ponto e vírgula

Tags: c++, code-golf

Faça um programa em C++ que exiba na tela os números de 1 até 1000, contando com esses dois, **porém sem utilizar o ponto e vírgula**.

Já fiz um esboço aqui porém eu tenho que escolher entre aparecer o 1 ou o 1000.

Complementando, meu código:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int x = 0) {

  while (x <= 1000 && std::cout << x++ << std::endl) {}
 }
```

Por que ele não exibe o número `1`? Pessoal, aqui, por exemplo; https://ideone.com/4663hX, a saída está correta. Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê de o g++ exibir a partir do `2`?

Comment: Tá. Isso eu li. E o que você tento? Por que sem o ponto e vírgula? Qual é o problema real? Isso é algum tipo codegolf ou é uma tarefa de casa? Explique melhor.

Comment: É um desafio pro pessoal. Não existe problema real.

Comment: [Essa pergunta está sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf).

Comment: Reabri a pergunta para ficar coerente com a maneira como a comunidade tratou outra pergunta de code golf. Ver a discussão no meta linkada pelo Guilherme Bernal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se é esse o objetivo, vamos lá:

## 76 bytes

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(int a,char**){while(printf("%d ",a++)&&a<1001){}}
```

Mas já se for em C, podemos deixar um pouco menor (ignorando os warnings, claro):

## 41 bytes

```
main(a){while(printf("%d ",a++)&&a<11){}}
```

Comment: Pode ver por que meu código não exibia o 1 ?

Comment: @ZebraDoMal não o vi. E edições sucessivas em menos de 5 minutos não entram no histórico.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, olha lá.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal Seu código funciona perfeitamente. Vai do 1 ao 1000.

Comment: Não vai. To compilando no G++, ele vai do 2 ao 1000.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22126005548133b0

Comment: Guilherme, por que no g++ parte do 2?

Comment: @ZebraDoMal O seu `x` é a quantidade de argumentos passados. Se for 1 argumento o seu código começa a mostrar do 1. Mas parece que você está passando algum argumento adicional para o executável. Configuração da IDE talvez?

Comment: Eu escrevo os códigos no Gedit e compilo no g++ padrão do Debian.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal Abra uma pergunta para isso. Isso aqui já ta virando uma bagunça.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Pois é, e ele abriu [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16248/saidas-diferentes-em-diferentes-compiladores) e agora a bagunça só piorou! hahaha :) O pior é que você já tinha respondido (eu também acho que ele tá passando um parâmetro a mais na linha de comando sem perceber).

Comment: @LuizVieira Acho que agora a coisa termina http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16516/429

Answer (score 2):

Uma possivel solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int num=0,char**){
    if(printf("%d\t",++num) && (&main + (&exit - &main)*(num/1000))(num+1)){}
}
```

`gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int x = 0) {
    while (x <= 10) {
    cout << x++ << endl;
    }
 }
```