# Saídas diferentes em diferentes compiladores

Tags: c++, compilação

Eu tenho esse código:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int x=1) {
  while (x <= 1000 && std::cout << x++ << std::endl) {}
 }
```

Eu o escrevi no Gedit, usando Debian, e compilei com o g++ do próprio Debian, sem nunca ter alterado nada. O compilador nunca apresentou problemas em outros códigos. Porém nesse meu código a saída na qual eu recebo é o intervalo de 2 a 1000.

E se eu compilar usando esse site https://ideone.com/4663hX, por exemplo, a saída é de 1 até 1000.

Algo interessante é que: se eu mudo o tipo de validação dentro do `while`, de menor ou igual a 1000 para menor que 1000, apenas, o programa passa a exibir o número 1.

O que está ocorrendo?

OBS: O código foi desenvolvido para um desafio. Logo, não se discute forma melhor de desenvolver a mesma saída.

Código Assembly:

```
.file   "tes.cpp"
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB969:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
.L4:
    cmpl    $1000, 8(%ebp)
    jg  .L2
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $1, 8(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    movl    (%eax), %edx
    subl    $12, %edx
    movl    (%edx), %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEEcvPvEv
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L2
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
.L3:
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L4
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE969:
    .size   main, .-main
    .type   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, @function
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB978:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L6
    cmpl    $65535, 12(%ebp)
    jne .L6
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, 8(%esp)
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, (%esp)
    call    __cxa_atexit
.L6:
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE978:
    .size   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, .-_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB979:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $65535, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE979:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 4
    .long   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Pode mostrar a saída para isso: `int main(int x, char** v) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }`? Deve ser 1.

Comment: É 1 mesmo. E eu já sabia disso. Algo interessante é que: se eu mudo o tipo de validação dentro do while, de menor ou igual para menor, apenas, o programa passa a exibir o núemero 1.

Comment: Qual a versão do GCC?

Comment: É a versão 4.7.

Comment: Estou ficando sem possibilidades... Compile seu código para assembly e adicione o resultado à pergunta. `g++ file.cpp -S -o file.s`

Comment: Eu quero o código assembly que seu compilador gera.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, adicionando o código gerado.

Comment: Hum... a minha impressão é que você está passando um argumento na linha de comando quando o valor começa com 2. Você pode verificar isso? Se for o caso, talvez a sua pergunta tenha um contexto muito local e deva ser fechada. Mas, não tenho certeza. Talvez seja uma boa motivação para incluir conhecimento sobre argumentos de linha de comando (e por isso eu mesmo postei uma resposta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código usa uma função main com a assinatura `int main(int)`, que **é ílegal**, como outras respostas já citaram. No entanto o GCC aceita tal assinatura gerando apenas um warning, não um erro. O código é compilado sem problemas e faz o esperado. O motivo do comportamento não está ai. (embora seja algo que deva ser corrigido de qualquer forma).

Passar um valor padrão para esse argumento não faz o menor sentido já que o sistema sempre vai chamar a função `main` passando explicitamente o valor. No caso vai ser `1` se você chamar o programa sem nenhum parametro na linha de comando, `2` se usar um parametro, `3` para dois parametros e assim vai. Note que no assmbly **fica claro e sem sombra *nenhuma* de dúvida** que o primeiro valor exibido na tela **é** o argumento passado para a função `main`.

```
main:                              // Início da função 'main'
.LFB969:                           // Prólogo: Alocar 16 bytes de stack
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp              // Fim do prólogo.
.L4:
    cmpl    $1000, 8(%ebp)         // Comparar o argumento com 1000
    jg  .L2                        // Se for maior, pule para L2. Não é.
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax          // Copie o argumento para EAX
    addl    $1, 8(%ebp)            // Incremente o argumento
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)          // Prepare para passar EAX como argumento
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)     // Prepare para passar std::cout como argumento
    call    _ZNSolsEi              // Chame 'std::cout << EAX';
```

Visto isso não há como questionar que o primeiro valor que sai na tela é o argumento da função `main`. Se você vê `2` é por que passou um parametro na linha de comando quando invocou o seu executável. Não há outra possibilidade.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que a função main deve receber apenas 0 ou 2 argumentos (int argc, char** argv), de acordo com o padrão C++. Como o seu código não está de acordo com as regras do C++, cada compilador pode trata-lo de forma diferente. O G++, por exemplo, gera um warning com o seu protótipo (use -Wmain, caso não esteja mostrando para você), mas parece trata-lo como se fosse o argc.

Como regra geral, garanta que seu código está de acordo com o padrão C++ e você terá menos problemas ao trocar de compilador/plataforma.

As formas definidas pelo padrão são as seguintes: 
`int main() {`

ou

`int main(int argc, char** argv) {`

Comment: Não achei necessário votar contra a sua resposta, mas ela não me parece muito precisa porque o comportamento não é necessariamente indefinido.

Comment: O comportamento pode não ser indefinida pelo fato de um determinado compilador aceitar essa forma. No entanto, o padrão C++ define apenas as formas sem argumentos e a forma com os argumentos argc e argv (seção 3.6.1), de forma que cada compilador pode fazer o que quiser em outros casos. Vou editar a resposta para deixar esse ponto mais claro.

Comment: Melhorou muito a sua resposta (principalmente com a indicação do warning no G++). :) De todas as formas, ainda acho meio incorreto afirmar que o código do OP "não está de acordo com as regras do C++", uma vez que o padrão (eu consultei a [última versão draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) apenas exige a existência desses dois protótipos mais comuns (e não impede outros, como você mesmo menciona). Ah, seria bacana também você incluir na sua resposta o link para o padrão que usou como referência.

Comment: P.S.: Também achei bom o conselho de buscar usar um desses dois protótipos para ter menos problemas ao trocar de compilador/plataforma.

Comment: Sim, eu recebia o aviso no console. Pode até ser que seja isso... Mas não sei ao certo. Por isso perguntei.

Answer (score 2):

Ao construir o seu programa em C++ você tem algumas opções para a declaração da função de entrada chamada `main`. As duas mais comuns são:

*1 - Sem se preocupar em receber e tratar argumentos de linha de comando do binário/executável. Por exemplo:*

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Ola mundo!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*2 - Recebendo e tratando argumentos de linha de comando do binário/executável. Por exemplo:*

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Ola mundo!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total de argumentos: " << argc << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << "Argumento #" << i << " = [" << argv[i] << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Porém, o fato é que a definição do protótipo dessa função em muitos compiladores permite algumas variações. No Visual Studio 2013, por exemplo, a "assinatura" do protótipo é descrita assim [na documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w63h9k.aspx):

> int main( int argc[ , char *argv[ ] [, char *envp[ ] ] ] );

Os colchetes (caracteres `[` e `]`) servem nesse contexto apenas para indicar a *opcionalidade* dos parâmetros da função (isto é, parâmetros entre colchetes são opcionais).

<sup>Nota: pode-se perceber que também é possível receber e tratar variáveis de ambiente com o parâmetro `envp`.</sup>

Outro detalhe é que a linguagem C++ permite que você indique, ao definir suas próprias funções, os parâmetros que são opcionais. Isso é feito simplesmente definindo um [valor padrão (*default*)](http://www.arnaut.eti.br/op/CPPAI02.htm#2.7) que deve ser utilizado caso o parâmetro não seja utilizado/informado na chamada.

Assim, ao construir o seu código da forma que fez, você simplesmente utilizou apenas o primeiro parâmetro (`argc`, que contém o número de argumentos da linha de comando do binário/executável, embora você o tenha renomeado para `x`). Como o segundo (e o terceiro) parâmetro de `main` é opcional, ele irá (muito provavelmente - isso depende da implementação do compilador) receber o valor `NULL`.

Além disso, você simplesmente redefiniu o valor padrão (default) desse argumento para `1`. Na prática, o simples fato de tê-lo ali faz com que você sempre receba ao menos o caminho e o nome do seu próprio binário/executável (segundo a documentação, esse é sempre o valor de argv[0], independentemente de você prover ou não argumentos adicionais na linha de comando), de forma que esse valor padrão é simplesmente inútil.

Isso tudo que eu argumentei não responde ao fato (alegado por você, mas ainda sem comprovação: simplesmente não consegui reproduzir nos meus testes locais com VS 2013) do resultado mudar dependendo do uso de menor (`<`) ou menor ou igual (`<=`). Ainda assim, conhecendo a documentação e o comportamento esperado da função `main`, eu tendo a acreditar que as variações do valor da sua variável `x` entre `1` e `2` decorram de você estar passando algum argumento na linha de comando (mesmo sem perceber).

De todas as formas, se o seu interesse é receber via linha de comando o número que deve ser utilizado para iniciar a sua contagem, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Validação dos argumentos da linha de comando
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Sintaxe: " << argv[0] << " <valor inicial>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    while (x <= 1000 && std::cout << x++ << std::endl) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse código eu fiz pra um outro post. No qual era pedido um código que exibisse os números de 1 a 1000 sem utilziar ponto e vírgula no código... Pois bem, o que você disse, que aquele valor será padrão, realmente. Eu comentei isso no outro post.

Comment: Cara, não me leve a mal, mas essa sua pergunta e a [outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16239/exibir-de-1-ate-1000-na-tela) me parecem basicamente a mesma. Além disso, você simplesmente ignorou todas as sugestões (em comentários e em respostas de AMBAS as perguntas) sobre o que pode ser o seu problema.